# How can I create a clickable event that changes position attributes in the CSS file of an outer div using only html and CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have a DIV container. inside it, I have a button. I want the button to be used to change the DIV's position attributes. I want the button click to shift the entire container to the left.
I have to do this without any scripting; only CSS and HTML.
is this possible? 
perhaps with buttonclick:active{stuff}?

Comment: You want to create an event,  you need JavaScript/JQuery.

Comment: Provide some code, else we can only imagine what you say.

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10162622/how-to-programmatically-apply-css-definitions-to-the-whole-page

Comment: Children (the button) cannot affect the position of a parent using CSS.

Comment: @Paulie_D Well, not directly, but of course they can do this indirectly with their own properties. For example if the parent is a floating container and your give negative margins to the inner element, or in case of collapsing margins.

Comment: Example: http://jsfiddle.net/aghvosy4/

Comment: Perhaps but that's not actually changing the position of the parent as such..that's redrawing the layout based on the child. Also,  probably not what the OP is asking for...which is unclear, too broad and without code...so basically...an **off-topic** trifecta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [checkbox hack](https://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/)

```css
#move-div {
  display: none;
}
#move-div:checked + .movable {
  left: -50px;
}
.movable {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #FF0000;
  padding: 10px;
}
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #000;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 3px #AAA;
}
```

```html
<input id="move-div" type="checkbox">
<div class="movable">
  <label class="button" for="move-div">Move the div</label>
</div>
```